# Error firestore

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I just started to learn firestore, i created simple app like a example from googleFirestore (in github).

When i change or create new data in firestore i get an error when my app is start in this line:

```
fatalError("Error")
```

I so understand the app is not like creating new data, how can I avoid this error and create data in real time?

My code:

```
private var hall: [Hall] = []
private var documents: [DocumentSnapshot] = []

fileprivate var query: Query? {
    didSet {
        if let listener = listener {
            listener.remove()
            observeQuery()
        }
    }
}

private var listener: ListenerRegistration?

fileprivate func observeQuery() {
    guard let query = query else { return }
    stopObserving()

    listener = query.addSnapshotListener { [unowned self] (snapshot, error) in
        guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
            print("Error fetching snapshot results: \(error!)")
            return
        }
        let models = snapshot.documents.map { (document) -> Hall in
            if let model = Hall(dictionary: document.data()) {
                return model
            } else {
                fatalError("Error")
            }
        }
        self.hall = models
        self.documents = snapshot.documents

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func stopObserving() {
    listener?.remove()
}

func baseQuery() -> Query {
    return Firestore.firestore().collection("searchStudios").limit(to: 50)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

    query = baseQuery()

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    observeQuery()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
    stopObserving()
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    set {}
    get {
        return .lightContent
    }
}

deinit {
    listener?.remove()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ResultTableViewCell
    cell.populate(hall: hall[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return hall.count
}
```

I can delete data, but not can add new data.

UPDATE:

struct Hall:

```
import Foundation

protocol DocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary: [String: Any])
}

struct Hall {

    var description: String
    var image: String
    var meters: Double
    var name: String
    var price: Int
    var studioHallAddress: String
    var studioHallName: String
    var studioHallLogo: String

    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "description": description,
            "image": image,
            "meters": meters,
            "name": name,
            "price": price,
            "studioHallAddrees": studioHallAddress,
            "studioHallName": studioHallName,
            "studioHallLogo": studioHallLogo
        ]
    }
}

extension Hall: DocumentSerializable {

    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        guard let description = dictionary["description"] as? String,
            let image = dictionary["image"] as? String,
            let meters = dictionary["meters"] as? Double,
            let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
            let price = dictionary["price"] as? Int,
            let studioHallAddress = dictionary["studioHallAddress"] as? String,
            let studioHallName = dictionary["studioHallName"] as? String,
            let studioHallLogo = dictionary["studioHallLogo"] as? String else { return nil }

        self.init(description: description,
                  image: image,
                  meters: meters,
                  name: name,
                  price: price,
                  studioHallAddress: studioHallAddress,
                  studioHallName: studioHallName,
                  studioHallLogo: studioHallLogo)
    }

}
```

Comment: What does your Hall initializer look like? Seems like it's having trouble converting the incoming dictionary to an object

Comment: @ToddKerpelman add my struct Hall

Comment: Have you put `FirebaseApp.configure()` in your AppDelegate?

Comment: Yes, but i resolved this problem